# Why do assert functions in unittest.TestCase have to be member functions?

Tags: python, python-unittest

The assert functions in `unittest.TestCase` are member functions. It means one has to call them by:

```
self.assertTrue(2 + 2 == 5)
```

instead of something like:

```
unittest.assertTrue(2 + 2 == 5)
```

I found it a bit inconvenient when I want to use those assert functions in another function, for example:

```
import unittest

def outside_test(test):
    test.assertTrue(2 + 2 == 5)

class T(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_something(self):
        outside_test(self)

t = T() 
t.test_something()
```

I had to pass `self` into `outside_test()` to use `assertTrue()`.

Is there any reason for those assert functions to be member functions of `unittest.TestCase`?

Comment: Use [pytest](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/).  Superior in basically every way.

Comment: I think the answer is just that that's the way `unittest` is architected. `TestCase`s allow for easier reuse of test logic in some scenarios. I'm curious as to why you would want to call a test outside of a `TestCase` (when using `unittest`). Do you have existing test functions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's just because they were copying JUnit, which uses instance methods for its assertions. This is also why everything is named in camelCase instead of under_scores.

There's no compelling advantage to using instance methods in Python; module-level functions likely would have been a more convenient interface, and [other Python testing frameworks](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/) use the `assert` statement. In Java, particularly back before `import static`, instance methods were most convenient.

Comment: I think there's a potential advantage when it comes to reuse, at least in some scenarios. Django's `TestCase` is an example.